# Floating action button's label

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Is it possible to show the label (like this [image]) of floating action button without using any third party library? I am using android support library for my fab and I want to know if I can show a label with it.

My code for FAB looks like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_visitdetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>
```

I'm not using any menu just a FAB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try something like this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_visitdetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Compose"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is just an example on how to do it, you can rearrange the code add remove code or whatever.

Comment: put your full Layout so i might be able to help please

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below code;

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
android:elevation="0dp"
app:fabSize="normal" />

<TextView
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="Compose"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_4"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

You actually want to use FloatingActionMenu.

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_visitdetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fab_label="fab_visitdetail_label"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionMenu>
```